# How to use feed to display recent 3 posts from WordPress to non-Wodpress site?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to display recent 3 posts from WordPress blog to Non-Wodpress site using feed ?
I just want to make a block on my HTML in another site.
the block shows last 3 posts from my blog.
how I can do it with feed?
my site feed is :
https://asool.org/blog/feed

Answer (score 0):

A good way to get data like that is to query the [WP Rest API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/requests/) and get the desired data via JSON. For your website the rest endpoint with the latest 3 posts would be https://asool.org/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=3

Comment: i can get the posts with  there thumbnail pictures?

Comment: Yes, add `_embed` to the URL to get the featured image as part of the Rest API request. `https://asool.org/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=3&_embed`